# Complexity of MPI barriers

Tags: mpi, time-complexity

What is the time complexity of MPI barriers? Do they scale for large number of cores (>> 10k)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Barrier complexity is *highly implementation-specific*. It could be linear, it could be logarithmic, or it could be better or worse. Some architectures provide dedicated networks for some collective operations, e.g. IBM's Blue Gene has a specialised global interrupt network which allows for very fast `MPI_BARRIER` implementation with almost constant complexity but only when performed over `MPI_COMM_WORLD`.

Comment: And, to address OP's second question, the supercomputer literature is full (maybe an exaggeration) of reports of MPI programs running on >>10k cores and I'd be surprised if none of them use barriers.

Answer (score 1):

While Hristo Iliev is correct, you can assume that any reasonable MPI implementation used on these scales has **logarithmic complexity** on collective operations. Yes this does scale >> 10k cores. There can still be a dramatic factor between different modern implementations. Also at this scale OS noise can have a very significant impact on collective operations (see e.g. [[1](http://www.unixer.de/publications/index.php?pub=108)]).

Answer (score 0):

The complexity should be no worse than O(log N) since one can implement a barrier as an allreduce over a single word, and allreduce scales as O(log N).